# How to make a default(TSource)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, default

In Linq When I call SingleOrDefault or FirstOrDefault how do I return something other than null for a particular object eg.

```
        List<CrazyControls> cc = CrazyControlRepository.All();
        cc.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == id).Render();
```

How do I make my CrazyControls return a default instance that implements a base Render() method?

Comment: That code snippet is weird. You are asking for "All" CrazyControls, and yet in the next line you say "throw an exception is there is more than one control."

Comment: Yeah...it's a little weird but legitimate. There should be only one CrazyControl with a given id if there are more I want it to blow up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [`DefaultIfEmpty(defaultValue)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx). This will ensure that if the collection is empty, it will be populated with a default instance of the type.

So you can do:

```
var defaultValue = new CrazyControl(...);

List<CrazyControls> cc = CrazyControlRepository.All();
cc.Where(p => p.Id == id).DefaultIfEmpty(defaultValue).First().Render();
```

The query expression needed to change a bit. The new one works like this:

1. Filter the collection according to the existing criteria. This will leave either one or no items in the filtered sequence.
2. Use `DefaultIfEmpty` to make sure that the sequence contains exactly one item (if it had one already, `DefaultIfEmpty` will do nothing).
3. Use `First` to get the single item. The reason I did not use `Single` instead of first is that if the predicate were different (or it changes in the future) and it accepted multiple items, `Single` would throw.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define this `something' that you want to return if there are no elements:

```
(cc.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == id) ?? new CrazyControls()).Render();
```

In other words you need to define the `default value`.